# Java Heap + Non-Heap total *not* exceeding 512MB by far, but memory usage > 512MB causing R14 errors

Tags: java, heroku, memory

Looking at the Heap and Non-Heap memory usage and total memory consumption on Heroku I see unexpected results.

Heap memory usage around 175MB
Non-Heap memory usage around 125MB
Total memory usage: 525MB

As the total memory usage is above 512MB I get R14 errors and the memory utilisation > 100% (102.8%).

Is this expected?

**EDIT**

I'm not using a custom Procfile and the Heroku dashboard displays following command to be used for starting the dyno: `web java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar`

It is using JDK 11 without any specific GC settings.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Added total memory usage graph.
Note for whole graph app is "idle" nobody is using it except some minimal number of request from my site.

With no specific memory setting (using Heroku defaults) 525MB is used.
Changing memory setting to -Xmx256m memory usage drops to 400 MB right away.
Changing it to -Xmx272m the memory goes up to 500MB.

[image]

Comment: What version of Java are you using and what GC settings do you have?  If you are using the default GC settings, please indicate so.

Comment: Note that the JVM statistics don't include every memory that the process uses. non-heap normally means things like stacks, string pool, reflection data etc. (all directly Java related) but not memory used by native code alone (could be JVM internals, file handles, dll libs etc.)

Comment: Also: with "heap memory usage around 175MB" do you mean that 175MB are reserved for the heap or that 175MB are actually used (i.e. filled with objects)?

Comment: I've updated the question regarding JDK version, GC and start command. Hope that helps. I think Thomas' last question is indeed interesting. Maybe the Heroku metrics dashboard is only display what is actually used and not what is being reserved. I have no such experience with Heroku to tell unfortunately.

Comment: I also added screenshot from the Heroku metrics page.

Comment: Reading https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support I see JDK11 apps already uses `-XX:+UseContainerSupport` by default. And also the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS will be `free, hobby or standard-1x: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2`. So maximum heap size would be 300MB. What is eating the memory then as I use only default settings...

Answer (score 0):

The 175MB of *used* heap is only representative of what portion the JVM is using of the total heap. If you're using the defaults, the committed heap is probably 300MB (this is not shown in the Heroku dashboard unfortunately).

The additional memory will come from the following:

- Non-heap (metaspace, code cache, some other things)
- Threads (each thread has it's own stack and consumed memory)
- JNI (native memory not managed by the JVM, see [this blog](http://jkutner.github.io/2018/01/03/mystery-memory-leaks-and-jni.html))
- External processes (if the JVM launches any other JVM or non-JVM process it will be reflected in total dyno memory)

I recommend the following:

- Lower your heap size (256MB may be enough)
- Lower some other defaults (`-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=50m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=80m`)
- Reduce the size of any thread pools (Tomcat?)

Finally, there is a case where lots of temporary direct memory maps remain associated with the process even though the JVM is done with them (i.e. the OS doesn't reclaim them and swaps them to disk). If you aren't seeing any adverse performance effects, this may be your case. This happens when there is lots of IO (like parsing tons of XML or JSON files, or generating PDFs).

Comment: Thanks @codefinger, setting -Xmx256m (by default 300 if I read docs) brings back total memory usage back from 525MB to approx. 400MB straight away... Quite interesting...

Comment: Changed it from -Xmx256m to -Xmx272 and total used memory from 400MB to 500 MB...

Comment: I've added another screenshot of the metrics under EDIT2.

Comment: Btw going above the 512MB is since I enabled the JVM Runtime Metrics this morning. I think that causes the bit of overhead the app needs just more than 512MB. It seems with the Heroku default settings (-Xmx300m) everything is balances so it just stays under 512MB.